# Hide or Show Data Fields in List Editor Form (Using Share point Designer )

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, office-365, xslt

I am facing an issue in developing Share point List Editor Form (Custom Form) using Share point Designer in O365. My requirement is, if column named "Payment Status" is "Pending For Payment" then show the Title field else don't show the field. Please refer my below code. My issue is, even if the status is "Pending For Payment" the title fields is not displayed in the form.

```
<xsl:if test="@Payment_x0020_Status!= 'Pending For Payment'">
    <tr>
        <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
            <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
            <nobr>Title<span class="ms-formvalidation"> *</span></nobr>
            </H3>
        </td>
        <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
            <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff1{$Pos}" ControlMode="Edit" FieldName="Title" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('u',concat('ff1',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Title')}"/>
            <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff1description{$Pos}" FieldName="Title" ControlMode="Edit"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Have I missed anything in the form? Can you please help me on this.

Full XSLT Code

```
<%@ Page language="C#" MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master"    Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage,Microsoft.SharePoint,Version=16.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" meta:progid="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document" meta:webpartpageexpansion="full"  %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %> <%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:ListFormPageTitle runat="server"/>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">
    <span class="die">
        <SharePoint:ListProperty Property="LinkTitle" runat="server" id="ID_LinkTitle"/>
    </span>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageImage" runat="server">
    <img src="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif?rev=44" width='1' height='1' alt="" data-accessibility-nocheck="true"/>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
<SharePoint:UIVersionedContent UIVersion="4" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <div style="padding-left:5px">
    </ContentTemplate>
</SharePoint:UIVersionedContent>
    <table class="ms-core-tableNoSpace" id="onetIDListForm">
     <tr>
      <td>
     <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" FrameType="None" ID="Main" Title="loc:Main"><ZoneTemplate>
        <WebPartPages:DataFormWebPart runat="server" EnableOriginalValue="False" DisplayName="Employee List" ViewFlag="8" ViewContentTypeId="" Default="FALSE" ListName="{3ACA5686-58D3-4E36-AC8F-0D7812940950}" ListId="3aca5686-58d3-4e36-ac8f-0d7812940950" PageType="PAGE_EDITFORM" PageSize="-1" UseSQLDataSourcePaging="True" DataSourceID="" ShowWithSampleData="False" AsyncRefresh="False" ManualRefresh="False" AutoRefresh="False" AutoRefreshInterval="60" NoDefaultStyle="TRUE" InitialAsyncDataFetch="False" Title="Employee List" FrameType="None" SuppressWebPartChrome="False" Description="" IsIncluded="True" PartOrder="2" FrameState="Normal" AllowRemove="True" AllowZoneChange="True" AllowMinimize="True" AllowConnect="True" AllowEdit="True" AllowHide="True" IsVisible="True" DetailLink="" HelpLink="" HelpMode="Modeless" Dir="Default" PartImageSmall="" MissingAssembly="Cannot import this Web Part." PartImageLarge="" IsIncludedFilter="" ExportControlledProperties="True" ConnectionID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" ID="g_2dfdb5ea_8282_4460_9480_e98c619f0bbd" ChromeType="None" ExportMode="All" __MarkupType="vsattributemarkup" __WebPartId="{2DFDB5EA-8282-4460-9480-E98C619F0BBD}" __AllowXSLTEditing="true" WebPart="true" Height="" Width=""><DataSources>
<SharePoint:SPDataSource runat="server" DataSourceMode="ListItem" SelectCommand="&lt;View&gt;&lt;Query&gt;&lt;Where&gt;&lt;Eq&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;ContentType&quot;/&gt;&lt;Value Type=&quot;Text&quot;&gt;Employee Employee Content type&lt;/Value&gt;&lt;/Eq&gt;&lt;/Where&gt;&lt;/Query&gt;&lt;/View&gt;" UseInternalName="True" UseServerDataFormat="True"><SelectParameters><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="ListItemId" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="0" Name="ListItemId"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="weburl" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="https://sample.sharepoint.com/sites/sampletest/sample" Name="weburl"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="ListID" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="{3ACA5686-58D3-4E36-AC8F-0D7812940950}" Name="ListID"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter>
            </SelectParameters><UpdateParameters><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="ListItemId" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="0" Name="ListItemId"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="weburl" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="https://sample.sharepoint.com/sites/sampletest/sample" Name="weburl"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="ListID" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="{3ACA5686-58D3-4E36-AC8F-0D7812940950}" Name="ListID"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter>
            </UpdateParameters><InsertParameters><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="ListItemId" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="0" Name="ListItemId"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="weburl" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="https://sample.sharepoint.com/sites/sampletest/sample" Name="weburl"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="ListID" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="{3ACA5686-58D3-4E36-AC8F-0D7812940950}" Name="ListID"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter>
            </InsertParameters><DeleteParameters><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="ListItemId" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="0" Name="ListItemId"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="weburl" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="https://sample.sharepoint.com/sites/sampletest/sample" Name="weburl"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="ListID" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="{3ACA5686-58D3-4E36-AC8F-0D7812940950}" Name="ListID"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter>
            </DeleteParameters>
</SharePoint:SPDataSource>
</DataSources>
<Xsl>






<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:dsp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl msxsl ddwrt" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:decimal-format NaN=""/>
    <xsl:param name="dvt_apos">&apos;</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="UserID" />
    <xsl:param name="WPPropertyBinding" />
    <xsl:param name="LogonUser"/>
    <xsl:param name="ManualRefresh"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:variable name="dvt_1_automode">0</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:template match="/" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:dsp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="($ManualRefresh = 'True')">
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top">
                            <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1"/>
                        </td>
                        <td width="1%" class="ms-vb" valign="top">
                            <img src="/_layouts/15/images/staticrefresh.gif" id="ManualRefresh" border="0" onclick="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__cancel')}" alt="Click here to refresh the dataview."/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="dvt_1">
        <xsl:variable name="dvt_StyleName">ListForm</xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row"/>
        <div>
            <span id="part1">
                <table border="0" width="100%">
                    <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.body">
                        <xsl:with-param name="Rows" select="$Rows"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </table>
            </span>
            <SharePoint:AttachmentUpload runat="server" ControlMode="Edit"/>
            <SharePoint:ItemHiddenVersion runat="server" ControlMode="Edit"/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="dvt_1.body">
        <xsl:param name="Rows"/>
        <tr>
            <td class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="99%" class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap"><IMG SRC="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif" width="1" height="18"/></td>
                        <td class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap">
                            <SharePoint:SaveButton runat="server" ControlMode="Edit" id="savebutton1"/>
                        </td>
                        <td class="ms-separator">&#160;</td>
                        <td class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap" align="right">
                            <SharePoint:GoBackButton runat="server" ControlMode="Edit" id="gobackbutton1"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap">
                <SharePoint:FormToolBar runat="server" ControlMode="Edit"/>
                <SharePoint:ItemValidationFailedMessage runat="server" ControlMode="Edit"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="$Rows">

            <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.rowedit"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <tr>
            <td class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="ms-descriptiontext" nowrap="nowrap">
                            <SharePoint:CreatedModifiedInfo ControlMode="Edit" runat="server"/>
                        </td>
                        <td width="99%" class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap"><IMG SRC="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif" width="1" height="18"/></td>
                        <td class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap">
                            <SharePoint:SaveButton runat="server" ControlMode="Edit" id="savebutton2"/>
                        </td>
                        <td class="ms-separator">&#160;</td>
                        <td class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap" align="right">
                            <SharePoint:GoBackButton runat="server" ControlMode="Edit" id="gobackbutton2"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="dvt_1.rowedit">
        <xsl:param name="Pos" select="position()"/>
        <tr>
            <td>

                <table border="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <xsl:if test="@PaymentStatus = 'Demo JB'">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                                <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
                                    <nobr>Title<span class="ms-formvalidation"> *</span>
                                    </nobr>
                                </H3>
                            </td>
                            <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                                <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff1{$Pos}" ControlMode="Edit" FieldName="Title" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('u',concat('ff1',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Title')}"/>
                                <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff1description{$Pos}" FieldName="Title" ControlMode="Edit"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                            <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
                                <nobr>PaymentStatus</nobr>
                            </H3>
                        </td>
                        <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                            <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff2{$Pos}" ControlMode="Edit" FieldName="PaymentStatus" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('u',concat('ff2',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@PaymentStatus')}"/>
                            <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff2description{$Pos}" FieldName="PaymentStatus" ControlMode="Edit"/>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <tr id="idAttachmentsRow">
                        <td nowrap="true" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel" width="20%">
                            <SharePoint:FieldLabel ControlMode="Edit" FieldName="Attachments" runat="server"/>
                        </td>
                        <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="80%">
                            <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="AttachmentsField" ControlMode="Edit" FieldName="Attachments" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('u','AttachmentsField','Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Attachments')}"/>
                            <script>
          var elm = document.getElementById("idAttachmentsTable");
          if (elm == null || elm.rows.length == 0)
          document.getElementById("idAttachmentsRow").style.display='none';
        </script>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                        <xsl:if test="$dvt_1_automode = '1'" ddwrt:cf_ignore="1">
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="99" class="ms-vb">
                                <span ddwrt:amkeyfield="ID" ddwrt:amkeyvalue="ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID))" ddwrt:ammode="view"></span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:if>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>   </Xsl>
<DataFields>
</DataFields>
<ParameterBindings>
         <ParameterBinding Name="ListItemId" Location="QueryString(ID)" DefaultValue="0"/>
         <ParameterBinding Name="weburl" Location="None" DefaultValue="https://sample.sharepoint.com/sites/sampletest/sample"/>
         <ParameterBinding Name="ListID" Location="None" DefaultValue="{3ACA5686-58D3-4E36-AC8F-0D7812940950}"/>
         <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_apos" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
         <ParameterBinding Name="ManualRefresh" Location="WPProperty[ManualRefresh]"/>
         <ParameterBinding Name="UserID" Location="CAMLVariable" DefaultValue="CurrentUserName"/>
         <ParameterBinding Name="Today" Location="CAMLVariable" DefaultValue="CurrentDate"/>
         <ParameterBinding Name="LogonUser" Location = "ServerVariable(LOGON_USER)" />
         <ParameterBinding Name="WPPropertyBinding" Location="Control(@Nationality)"  DefaultValue="asssss" />
     </ParameterBindings>
</WebPartPages:DataFormWebPart>

        </ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
      </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
<SharePoint:UIVersionedContent UIVersion="4" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
    </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</SharePoint:UIVersionedContent>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="FormCustomRedirectControl" AllowMultipleControls="true"/>
    <SharePoint:UIVersionedContent UIVersion="4" runat="server"><ContentTemplate>
        <SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="forms.css" runat="server"/>
    </ContentTemplate></SharePoint:UIVersionedContent>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderTitleLeftBorder" runat="server">
<table cellpadding="0" height="100%" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
 <tr><td class="ms-areaseparatorleft"><img src="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif?rev=44" width='1' height='1' alt="" data-accessibility-nocheck="true"/></td></tr>
</table>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderTitleAreaClass" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript" id="onetidPageTitleAreaFrameScript">
    if (document.getElementById("onetidPageTitleAreaFrame") != null)
    {
        document.getElementById("onetidPageTitleAreaFrame").className="ms-areaseparator";
    }
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderBodyAreaClass" runat="server">
<SharePoint:StyleBlock runat="server">
.ms-bodyareaframe {
    padding: 8px;
    border: none;
}
</SharePoint:StyleBlock>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderBodyLeftBorder" runat="server">
<div class='ms-areaseparatorleft'><img src="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif?rev=44" width='8' height='100%' alt="" data-accessibility-nocheck="true"/></div>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderTitleRightMargin" runat="server">
<div class='ms-areaseparatorright'><img src="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif?rev=44" width='8' height='100%' alt="" data-accessibility-nocheck="true"/></div>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderBodyRightMargin" runat="server">
<div class='ms-areaseparatorright'><img src="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif?rev=44" width='8' height='100%' alt="" data-accessibility-nocheck="true"/></div>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderTitleAreaSeparator" runat="server"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

For debugging purpose, display value of @Payment_x0020_Status in td and see that it is coming exactly as you are comparing. 
Also what is type of column ? is it lookup or text/choice etc ?

```
<td>
<xsl:value-of select="@Payment_x0020_Status"/>
</td>
```

Comment: @Siddhath Vaghasia, Yes its the Choice field, How to display the value in td? Can you please help me on the same.

Comment: @Siddarth Vaghasia, I tried the way you mentioned but no value is displayed in the Page, I tried for other fields in the similar way, but in all cases it returns empty value only. Any other modifications I need to make in the form.

Comment: Are you sure you are using valid Xpath, if the scope of above variable does not fall within the valid xpath, you might have to change select attribute to something like select="/yourpath/@Payment_x0020_Status"

Comment: What will the XPath in Share-point, is it similar to <xsl:value-of select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/@Payment_x0020_Status"/>

Comment: Any updates on my previous query.

Comment: Ideally it should work with "<xsl:value-of select="@Payment_x0020_Status"/>" . I might need to refer your whole XSLT to see what can be reason, can you upload XSLT file somewher for reference ?

Comment: How to upload the file here.

Comment: I have updated the question with the code. Please verify.

Comment: your code looks correct...not sure why it is not working you have to use @Payment_x0020_Status only...this is correct xpath

Comment: Yes. Agreed. Tried both PaymentStatus and Payment_x0020_Status